# RequiredFieldValidator on 3 fields concatenated?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm new to RequiredFieldValidator.  I have three text boxes that I would like to concatenate and then validate that there are a total of 10 numbers there.  Does the RequiredFieldValidator have this functionality built in? (vb.net)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`RequiredFieldValidator` only works on one Control (making it required). You would need to use a `CustomValidator` to meet your needs.

Below is a Useful link: [best way to check if 3 textboxes are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380669/best-way-to-check-if-3-textboxes-are-empty)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is a much easier way using CustomValidator

```
<asp:CustomValidator
    ID="CustomValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="You must fill at textbox"
    OnServerValidate="Total_ServerValidate" />

protected void Total_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
//Codehere ..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ou can use the custom validator control in this scenario. So for example:

```
<b>A: </b><asp:TextBox id="A" runat="server"><br />
<b>B: </b><asp:TextBox id="B" runat="server">
<b>C: </b><asp:TextBox id="C" runat="server">
<asp:Button id="Submit" Text="Submit" /><br />

<asp:CustomValidator id="AtLeastTen" runat="server"  
  ErrorMessage="10 length required" 
  Display="Dynamic"
  OnServerValidate="AtLeastTenNumbers_ServerValidate" 
   />
```

Then on the code behind:

```
Sub AtLeastTenNumbers_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, _
  ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) 

    If A.Text.Length + B.Text.Length + C.Text.Length > 10 Then
        args.IsValid = true 
    Else
        args.IsValid = false 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Also note that you might need code to check if they are indeed numbers. The above code just checks the length and assumes that they are numbers already.

Have a look at custom validator:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9522/CustomValidator-dependent-on-multiple-controls

Comment: I was thinking a 4th textbox that got appended each of the 3 values to it and then a Regex validator on that one  with expression something like `^[0-9]\d{10}\s*$` or something similar?